# Reference magento path php

Tags: magento-1.9, php

Hi I have a php script that starts like this:

```
<?php

require_once('app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
umask(0);
Mage::app();
```

How do I call app/Mage.php from a directory other than root??
i.e I have my script in public_html/shell but app is in public_html/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In normal case you can call it like:

```
<?php
require_once('../app/Mage.php'); // "../" represent the parent directory
umask(0);
Mage::app();
```

If you are running the script via a cron job, use below to make sure that the cron is in the correct directory:

```
<?php
chdir(dirname(__FILE__));
require_once '../app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
require_once('../app/Mage.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to write this thigs if your script in shell folder

You can create shell script and also you can use it from browser and CLI as well . below file name is `test.php` in `shell` folder

```
 <?php
    //ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
    require_once 'abstract.php';
    class Mage_Shell_Test extends Mage_Shell_Abstract{

        public function run(){
            Mage::app();
           //you can do whatever you want to do in this method

        }

        public function _validate() {
           // this function allows you to use this script from browser  
             return true;
        }



    }

    $shell = new Mage_Shell_Test();
    $shell->run();

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your script is required to be outside Magento folder then just use chdir() as first line.

In your case:

```
<?php

chdir('/var/www/fullpath_where_index_php_is');
require_once('app/Mage.php');

umask(0);
```